# API for advertising secondary ble service on device(Peripheral mode)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattService.html),it seems there are two types of ble(Bluetooth Low Energy)services-Primary and Secondary.A **secondary service** is included in a **primary service**,kind of nesting a service inside other service.However I didnt find any api to create a secondary service and advertise it.

Whenever we use the following code for advertising a service,the service gets added as primary service.

```
 new AdvertiseData.Builder()
               // .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(DeviceProfile.SERVICE_UUID))
```

Is there a way to specify the type of service, when advertising it?I have being trying to build an app to advertise a secondary service and a client app which will connect to this secondary service and read data.Please let me know if anyone know a workaround to do it.I have done lot of research but could not find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

After Successfully advertising you can do this:

```
BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(serviceUUID,BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_SECONDARY);
    service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);
    mGattServer.addService(service);
```

Comment: This will add the service as primary service..I want to expose it as secondary service..

Comment: will check and let you know..I wanted to use AdvertiseData.Builder() API to advertise the service..Will check if there is any difference with using your approach

Comment: @rupeshjain did adding the secondary service to the GattServer after advertising has started fix your problem?

Comment: @jschlepp I didnt try since we changed the architecture to make all the services as primary..

Comment: @rupeshjain Okay, thanks for getting back to me. We had to end up doing something similar.